# Using Kingfisher how can I cache a new image which has kept the same URL?

Tags: swift, kingfisher

I realise there is an option for force refreshing, but I am looking for a solution which will still cache the images and not have to load it in from a network every time.

Currently, if I try to set a new image with the same URL it just shows the previous image as that has been cached and it is not overwriting the new url.

Comment: It is done with the default configuration.

Comment: How do you mean? If I try to set a new image with the same URL it just shows the previous image as that has been cached and it is not overwriting the new url.

Comment: Your title and your question are not referring to the same actually. You ask for updating an image which has changed with the same URL but in your question you are asking for a caching system.

Comment: You are right, sorry about that.

Comment: Can you show us the code your are using ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found my own solution though it may not be the best way.

First when I have updated an image I change a public variable to reflect this. I then check to see if the image is cached and remove it if it is.

```
import Kingfisher

if self.imageHasUpdated {
      if ImageCache.default.isImageCached(forKey: image.absoluteString).cached {
               print("Image is cached")
               ImageCache.default.removeImage(forKey: image.absoluteString)
               self.imageHasUpdated = false
      }
}
```

Finally I update the image as normal.

```
imageView.kf.setImage(with: imageURL, placeholder: nil, options: nil)
```

Comment: This is only work for local checking, right ?.How it is woking remotely? Like, from another device I changed the image how it will reflect in my device?